# attach to process and load a perl script

Tags: perl, debugging, gdb

is there a way to attach to a running Perl process using GDB
and loading the script symbols?
I was able to attach to the process but I don't know how to load
the script symbols.

is this possible?

Comment: GDB cannot read the perl script symbols, it reads the symbols from the C source of the perl binary (if you compiled perl with debugging symbols). To read symbols (variables) from a perl script you can use the [perl debugger](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug)

Comment: See also [How can I attach a debugger to a running Perl process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8836711/2173773) and [Enbugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Enbugger)

Comment: Maybe you could find some hints by using module [`B::Debug`](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Debug) !